Hyperlink Css Not Working If Placed In External Stylesheet (Bootstrap Included) And Working Properly When Placed Inside The Same Page
The css style for a hyper link color: black; not working when it placed in external stylesheet.
Example 1 (css also written inside the html page)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"> For Question </a>
</body>
<style>
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: green;
    transition: 1s;
}
</style>
</html>

This Is working perfectly fine without any issues.but
Example 2 (css written in external file and included with link tag in html
Example_2.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Example_2.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"> For Question </a>
</body>
<style>

</style>
</html>

Example_2.css
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: green;
    transition: 1s;
}

Attaching informtaion showing in console.
I need to solve this issue for giving hyperlink a default color without !important property in css. Because if I use !important it will be affected to all hyperlinks inside the page. Then I will be no longer able to customize Hperlinks with special colors inside the same page.
for example:
<a href="#" class="default"> Text Here 1 </a> I need this Hyperlink with default style and <a href="#" class="special"> Text Here 2 </a> this with special style.
Also giving class names to all Hyperlinks which are defaults will make the code more complex.
Can Anyone Figure out the problem and help me.

Did you check the console for a given error? Maybe the CSS file cannot be found. And try linking the stylesheet like so /Example_2.css, it should be no problem because the CSS should be in the same directory.
If you want to give each link a different color you could do nth-child(), this will let you avoid giving extra classes to the anchor tags. But I'm not really sure why you want to avoid giving classes, this would make things a lot easier.

This is likely due to the order in which CSS files are being loaded in your second example. The Bootstrap CSS is loaded AFTER your custom stylesheet, and can override its content. Try loading your custom stylesheet after the Bootstrap stylesheet, like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Example_2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"> For Question </a>
</body>
<style>

</style>
</html>


It Worked. I really didn't know about the priority order of loading css

glad it worked!
